# How to use WWW::Mechanize to login via POST and accept cookies and browse web site?

Tags: web, mechanize

I have read various help and documentation pages regarding WWW::Mechanize, which seems to be the answer for what I want to do, but I have been unable to find any good examples and have been unsuccessful in hacking my own script.

I have successfully installed WWW::Mechanize and am trying to get it to do what I need...

*Basically, I am trying to automate the login process to a web site and then to go to a specific page(s).*

The normal human process is for me to:
  1. Go an "identity server" which is an https web site that serves up a simple login form (with some hidden values but has a username and password and a submit button [and a 'save my login' option]).
  2. Upon successful login, the "identity server" automatically redirects me to the password-protected web site as an authenticated user.

I have been able to use WWW::Mechanize to see the source code of the login page, but I do not understand how to POST the login information back to the server to get logged in and redirected.

The basic script I have tested is below. Can anyone help me out or direct me to a resource where it might have an example to allow me to help myself?

Also, I do not think it matters, but the web sites involved are pretty-much based on Microsoft server and DNN.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $start = qq|https://login.foo.org/default.aspx|;
$mech->get($start);

my $username_field = 'ctl00$MainContent$tbUser';
my $password_field = 'ctl00$MainContent$tbPassword';

my $username = "123456";
my $password = "mypasssword";

$mech->field($username_field,$username);
$mech->field($password_field,$password);
$mech->submit(); # to get login cookie
my $results = $mech->submit();

if ($results->is_success) {
    print $results->content;
} else {
       print $results->message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is after you submit the form the website you are trying to log in is placing a session cookie so that it can verify you are a verified user and you don't need to re-authenticate yourself after it redirects to your private logged in page.

The above script you wrote redirects you to the secured private page after you log in but finds out the session cookie is not present any more. So you are actually not enjoying the benefits of a a logged in user. Basically you need to enable cookie saving.

Here is the python code you need [using same Mechanize library you are using] that should work.:

```
    import cookielib
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj) # Now cookie jar can store the loggedIn session cookie so you can access the private pages of a logged in user.
    #Extra code may not be required for you
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False) #Some websites won't allow scripts by placing a robots.txt file in their root directory so you need to set robots to false. e.g. Google
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')] #Some website allows only browsers to view them. So this is a trick(hack) which will be required for accessing such websites.
```

Now when you submit the form you should be able to redirect to the secured logged in page without you being logged out. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am not sure about Python. I don't know what that is or how it fits into a Perl script. Can you explain this using the Perl implementation of WWW::Mechanize?